# Hiding or removing controller name in url using routes for seo purpose = codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am using one controller. How can I remove or hide the controller name on my URL using routes? 
I already set my .htaccess to remove my index.php. I've tried lots of code from other similar questions but I don't have luck. I don't know If I have a problem on my live server because on my previous project I used this code

```
$route['del/(:any)'] = "my_cotroller";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

and this works perfectly fine but when I tried to use it on my current project it didn't work.
This is my default route

```
$route['default_controller'] = "my_cotroller";
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

I want to archive a URL like http://www.sample.com/login but my current route code gives me this http://www.sample.com/my_controller/login.

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple approach when i use CI:

Example Controller:

```
<?php
class Haha extends CI_Controller
{
    public function check()
    {           
        $this->load->view('path/to/check/view');
    }

    public function choke()
    {
        $this->load->view('path/to/choke/view');
    }
}
```

Example routes:

```
//same name with C method
$route['check'] = 'haha/check';
$route['choke/(:any)'] = 'haha/choke';

//or custom route name
$route['squirrel'] = 'haha/check';
$route['woohoo/(:any)'] = 'haha/choke';
```

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

Access the uri:

```
http://yoursite.com/check
http://yoursite.com/choke/whatever

//or

http://yoursite.com/squirrel
http://yoursite.com/woohoo/whatever
```

Addition:
Here is complete routes from my old project using CI, maybe you can get something.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['default_controller'] = 'sitehome';

$route['page'] = 'sitehome/page';
$route['page/who-we-are'] = 'site/whoweare';
$route['page/why-use-us'] = 'site/whyus';
$route['page/about-us'] = 'site/about';
$route['page/contact-us'] = 'site/contact';
$route['page/news'] = 'site/news/news';
$route['page/topics'] = 'site/topic';
$route['page/polls'] = 'site/polls';
$route['page/results'] = 'site/result';
$route['agent/detail/(:any)'] = 'site/agentdetail';
$route['register'] = 'site/register';
$route['login'] = 'site/login';

$route['user/home'] = 'usermain';
$route['user/edit-account'] = 'user/editaccount';
$route['user/retire'] = 'user/retired';
$route['user/business/data'] = 'user/business';
$route['user/business/topic/create'] = 'user/topic/topiccreate';
$route['user/business/topic/view'] = 'user/topic/topicview';
$route['user/business/topic/edit/(:num)'] = 'user/topic/topicedit';
$route['user/inbox'] = 'user/inbox';
$route['user/message/read/(:any)'] = 'user/readmessage';
$route['user/provider/list'] = 'user/providerlist';
$route['user/provider/send-message/(:any)'] = 'user/providerlist/sendmessage';
$route['user/notification'] = 'user/notified';
$route['user/inquiry'] = 'user/inquiry';

//testing purpose
$route['percobaan'] = 'coba/percobaan';

$route['poll'] = 'site/polls/retrievePoll';

//serve response
$route['response/single-poll'] = 'api/ResponseData/serveHomePoll';
$route['response/multi-poll'] = 'api/ResponseData/servePoll';

$route['404_override'] = 'notFound';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;

/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

Notes :

> `http://example.com/business/` will fail or not exist.

Good luck.

Comment: So I need to create individual routes for every page? How about creating a routes that automatically handles all and removes the controller name? Cuz, this code does automatically remove the controller name $route['del/(:any)'] = "my_cotroller";
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1'; however this is no longer working to my current project and I don't know why.

Comment: `(:any)` means you can give anything on uri as long as the char is permitted. `$route['choke/any'] = 'haha/choke';` will bring user to the haha/choke controller whatever they use in segment 2. except you filter it on your controller or model only accept some words on segment 2.

Comment: If I got it right, it could be like this. $route['choke2/(:any)'] = 'haha/choke2'; $route['choke3/(:any)'] = 'haha/choke3'; $route['choke4/(:any)'] = 'haha/choke4';

Comment: Yes, example : `$route['choke2/(:any)'] = 'haha/choke2';` accessible via `http://example.com/choke2/what`, `http://example.com/choke2/bla-bla`, `http://example.com/choke2/aw-so-some`. What ever the 2(second) uri segment will be pointing to `haha/choke2`. But this uri `http://example.com/choke2/else/if` will fail because containing third segment as it not declared on routes.

Comment: No problem, glad can help.

Comment: Oops! One more thing. This works only for static pages. I have a function that has a switch case on it and all those elements are dynamic url (user posting). I've tried to create individual routes for everyone but what if user added new post? how can I make a dynamic routes for that function. I've tried $route['choke2/(:any)'] = 'haha/choke2'; but the any doesn't work. Also how can I completely remove the controller name when I click the link?

Comment: how the dynamic link look like ? paste it here

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom route in config/routes.php - for example:

```
$route['about'] = 'name_controller/about';
```

Then, http://example.com/about
goes to http://example.com/name_controller/about

See more [http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)