# How can I eliminate the controller name in the url via routes in = codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

This is a follow up question for my first question from [Hiding or removing controller name in url using routes for seo purpose = codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774571/hiding-or-removing-controller-name-in-url-using-routes-for-seo-purpose-codeign)

I need to hide or remove the controller name from the url. So I followed the answer given to me by Nucleo 1985, this works perfectly fine for static pages. I know that my question is somewhat different so I got different solution.

I am using one controller.

I have a function in my controller that has a switch case on it. Every case contains url. example (http://www.sample.com/my_controller/my_function/my_case_url). The /my_case_url is the dynamic.

I created individual routes for every function and it's quite hustle and not applicable to my function that has a switch case url.

My question is.

How can I achieve a url like http://www.sample.com/my_function/ and http://www.sample.com/my_function/my_case_url/? (The function name must be removed or hide when the link is clicked and redirect to the page)

I need this for SEO purposes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this will work same as your first question

```
// it will go to my_controller index    
$route['my_function'] = 'my_controller'; 

// you can set specific controller method remove method will go to index.
$route['chomy_functione/(:any)'] = 'my_controller/my_function';
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be done from project_name/application/config/routes.php this file.Add a line

```
$route['url_first/url_second'] = "any_controller_name/function_name";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a method _remap() in your controller

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping

Put the following code inside your controller

```
/**
 * Intercept all calls to this class. 
 * 
 * @access private
 * @param string
 * @param array
 * @return boolean
 */
function _remap($method, $params)
{
    // If method exists, call that method.
    if (method_exists($this, $method) !== false) return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);

    // If method is actually an existing permalink, show permalink's content
    if ($this->SomeModel->exists(array('permalink' => $method))) return $this->view($method);

    // Non-existing method
    show_404();
}
```