# Removing index.php part of URI using .htaccess file in Codeigniter with Simplicity

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I am trying to remove the section of index.php from my URI's in my website. I am not versed at all in htaccess or apache, so if your solution has to do with that, please explain in simple terms that I can understand.

This is just a learning project at the moment but I plan on using this website as a selling place for my home based business, so it is important that I figure this out for a more professional look.

**Please Note:** I have read and tried the example given in the CodeIgniter User Guide, and I have not succeeded. Perhaps its where I am placing the .htaccess file.

Currently I am trying to rewrite the file that is included and be default has only one line:

```
Deny from all
```

**Again, I have already tried the code below from the CodeIgniter user guide without success.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I am including the main controller, the config.php file, the routes.php file, and the view for my basic navigation for my website below. Perhaps you could find an error.

**Main Controller**

```
    <?php
session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $title = 'ImpactU Online';
        $subtitle = 'Is Your Next Web Project Ready?';
        $subhead = 'A Little About Us';
        $this->load->view('template/header', array(
            'title' => $title,
            'subtitle' => $subtitle,
            'subhead' => $subhead,
        ));
        $this->load->view('home');
        $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }

}
```

**config.php**

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Base Site URL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| URL to your CodeIgniter root. Typically this will be your base URL,
| WITH a trailing slash:
|
|   http://example.com/
|
| If this is not set then CodeIgniter will guess the protocol, domain and
| path to your installation.
|
*/
$config['base_url'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI PROTOCOL
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item determines which server global should be used to retrieve the
| URI string.  The default setting of 'AUTO' works for most servers.
| If your links do not seem to work, try one of the other delicious flavors:
|
| 'AUTO'            Default - auto detects
| 'PATH_INFO'       Uses the PATH_INFO
| 'QUERY_STRING'    Uses the QUERY_STRING
| 'REQUEST_URI'     Uses the REQUEST_URI
| 'ORIG_PATH_INFO'  Uses the ORIG_PATH_INFO
|
*/
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URL suffix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option allows you to add a suffix to all URLs generated by CodeIgniter.
| For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
*/

$config['url_suffix'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Language
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which set of language files should be used. Make sure
| there is an available translation if you intend to use something other
| than english.
|
*/
$config['language'] = 'english';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Default Character Set
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This determines which character set is used by default in various methods
| that require a character set to be provided.
|
*/
$config['charset'] = 'UTF-8';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable/Disable System Hooks
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you would like to use the 'hooks' feature you must enable it by
| setting this variable to TRUE (boolean).  See the user guide for details.
|
*/
$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Class Extension Prefix
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This item allows you to set the filename/classname prefix when extending
| native libraries.  For more information please see the user guide:
|
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html
| http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html
|
*/
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Allowed URL Characters
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This lets you specify with a regular expression which characters are permitted
| within your URLs.  When someone tries to submit a URL with disallowed
| characters they will get a warning message.
|
| As a security measure you are STRONGLY encouraged to restrict URLs to
| as few characters as possible.  By default only these are allowed: a-z 0-9~%.:_-
|
| Leave blank to allow all characters -- but only if you are insane.
|
| DO NOT CHANGE THIS UNLESS YOU FULLY UNDERSTAND THE REPERCUSSIONS!!
|
*/
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enable Query Strings
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| By default CodeIgniter uses search-engine friendly segment based URLs:
| example.com/who/what/where/
|
| By default CodeIgniter enables access to the $_GET array.  If for some
| reason you would like to disable it, set 'allow_get_array' to FALSE.
|
| You can optionally enable standard query string based URLs:
| example.com?who=me&what=something&where=here
|
| Options are: TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
| The other items let you set the query string 'words' that will
| invoke your controllers and its functions:
| example.com/index.php?c=controller&m=function
|
| Please note that some of the helpers won't work as expected when
| this feature is enabled, since CodeIgniter is designed primarily to
| use segment based URLs.
|
*/
$config['allow_get_array']      = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['controller_trigger']   = 'c';
$config['function_trigger']     = 'm';
$config['directory_trigger']    = 'd'; // experimental not currently in use

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you have enabled error logging, you can set an error threshold to
| determine what gets logged. Threshold options are:
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| application/logs/ folder. Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['log_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Date Format for Logs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Each item that is logged has an associated date. You can use PHP date
| codes to set your own date formatting
|
*/
$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cache Directory Path
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Leave this BLANK unless you would like to set something other than the default
| system/cache/ folder.  Use a full server path with trailing slash.
|
*/
$config['cache_path'] = '';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you use the Encryption class or the Session class you
| MUST set an encryption key.  See the user guide for info.
|
*/
$config['encryption_key'] = 'C6hVYfUz5FQ2gMOz1TaT74CfSBKjR1dx';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'sess_cookie_name'        = the name you want for the cookie
| 'sess_expiration'         = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.
| 'sess_expire_on_close'    = Whether to cause the session to expire automatically
|   when the browser window is closed
| 'sess_encrypt_cookie'     = Whether to encrypt the cookie
| 'sess_use_database'       = Whether to save the session data to a database
| 'sess_table_name'         = The name of the session database table
| 'sess_match_ip'           = Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data
| 'sess_match_useragent'    = Whether to match the User Agent when reading the session data
| 'sess_time_to_update'     = how many seconds between CI refreshing Session Information
|
*/
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = FALSE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix' = Set a prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain' = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'   =  Typically will be a forward slash
| 'cookie_secure' =  Cookies will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
|
*/
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Global XSS Filtering
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Determines whether the XSS filter is always active when GET, POST or
| COOKIE data is encountered
|
*/
$config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross Site Request Forgery
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Enables a CSRF cookie token to be set. When set to TRUE, token will be
| checked on a submitted form. If you are accepting user data, it is strongly
| recommended CSRF protection be enabled.
|
| 'csrf_token_name' = The token name
| 'csrf_cookie_name' = The cookie name
| 'csrf_expire' = The number in seconds the token should expire.
*/
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Output Compression
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Enables Gzip output compression for faster page loads.  When enabled,
| the output class will test whether your server supports Gzip.
| Even if it does, however, not all browsers support compression
| so enable only if you are reasonably sure your visitors can handle it.
|
| VERY IMPORTANT:  If you are getting a blank page when compression is enabled it
| means you are prematurely outputting something to your browser. It could
| even be a line of whitespace at the end of one of your scripts.  For
| compression to work, nothing can be sent before the output buffer is called
| by the output class.  Do not 'echo' any values with compression enabled.
|
*/
$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Master Time Reference
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Options are 'local' or 'gmt'.  This pref tells the system whether to use
| your server's local time as the master 'now' reference, or convert it to
| GMT.  See the 'date helper' page of the user guide for information
| regarding date handling.
|
*/
$config['time_reference'] = 'local';


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Rewrite PHP Short Tags
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your PHP installation does not have short tag support enabled CI
| can rewrite the tags on-the-fly, enabling you to utilize that syntax
| in your view files.  Options are TRUE or FALSE (boolean)
|
*/
$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Reverse Proxy IPs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy IP
| addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
| header in order to properly identify the visitor's IP address.
| Comma-delimited, e.g. '10.0.1.200,10.0.1.201'
|
*/
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';


/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/config.php */
```

**routes.php**

```
    <?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
|   example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
|   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There area two reserved routes:
|
|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
|   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided
| in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
*/

$route['default_controller'] = "main";
$route['404_override'] = '';


/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

**Header View With Basic Site Navigation Links**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title><?php echo html_escape($title); ?></title>
        <meta name="descripton" content="Is Your Next Web Project Ready? Check out ImpactU Online! We got this. DISCLAIMER: ImpactU is not a real company and any similarity to any other company so namesd is purely by chance. This site is for educational purposes ONLY."/>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/favicon.ico"); ?>" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="<?php echo base_url("assets/images/favicon.ico"); ?>" type="image/x-icon">
        <link 
            href="<?php
            echo base_url('assets/css/impactU.css');
            ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            />
        <link 
            href="<?php
            echo base_url('assets/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
            ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            />
        <link 
            href="<?php
            echo base_url('assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css');
            ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/pure-min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/pure/0.5.0/grids-responsive-min.css">
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/yui/yui-min.js"></script>
        <link 
            href="<?php
            echo base_url('assets/css/side-menu.css');
            ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
            />
        <script>
            (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
                i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
                i[r] = i[r] || function () {
                    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
                }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
                a = s.createElement(o),
                        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
                a.async = 1;
                a.src = g;
                m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
            })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-57039794-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="layout">
            <!-- Menu toggle -->
            <a href="#menu" id="menuLink" class="menu-link">
                <!-- Hamburger icon -->
                <span></span>
            </a>

            <div id="menu">
                <div class="pure-menu pure-menu-open">
                    <a class="pure-menu-heading" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">ImpactU</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li  <?php echo $title == 'ImpactU Online' ? 'class = "menu-item-divided pure-menu-selected"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>" title="Home">
                                <i class="fa fa-home"></i>
                                Home
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li  <?php echo $title == 'ImpactU Blog' ? 'class = "menu-item-divided pure-menu-selected"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('blog'); ?>" title="News, Annoucements, and Web Management Tips">
                                <i class="fa fa-rss"></i>
                                Blog
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li <?php echo $title == 'ImpactU Store' ? 'class = "menu-item-divided pure-menu-selected"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('store'); ?>" title="Find resources for your next web project">
                                <i class="fa fa-money"></i>
                                Store
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li <?php echo $title == 'ImpactU Contact' ? 'class = "menu-item-divided pure-menu-selected"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('contact'); ?>" title="Get in touch with us">
                                <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                                Contact
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li <?php echo $title == 'ImpactU About' ? 'class = "menu-item-divided pure-menu-selected"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('about'); ?>" title="Find out about this school project">
                                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                                About
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li <?php echo $title == 'ImpactU Feedback' ? 'class = "menu-item-divided pure-menu-selected"' : ''; ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('feedback'); ?>" title="Let me know what you think">
                                <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                                Feedback
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="menu-item-divided <?php echo $title == 'ImpactU Company Login' ? 'pure-menu-selected' : ''; ?>"><a href="<?php echo site_url('company_home'); ?>" title="Employees enter here">
                                <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                                Company Login
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="main">
                <div class="header">
                    <h1><?php echo html_escape($title); ?></h1>
                    <h2><?php echo html_escape($subtitle); ?></h2>
                </div>

                <div class="content">
                    <h2 class="content-subhead"><?php echo html_escape($subhead); ?></h2>
```

Thank you in advance. Sorry about including so much code, but I like to show that I have the work in order to look for a solution before I ask. I have researched this already a lot on Stack Overflow, but haven't been able to find a solution. Please test your solution before submitting it as a courtesy. I have found a lot of people are just saying look at the user guide because it seemingly says to do one thing but **as I have stated before, I have tried to published solution in the user guide and failed**.

Comment: Check my answer on this question, if you find it useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27774571/hiding-or-removing-controller-name-in-url-using-routes-for-seo-purpose-codeign/27774648?noredirect=1#comment43996224_27774648

Comment: You Sir, have my respect. That is a very good solution to this problem.

Comment: No problem, its nice can helping each other. Notice on the htaccess after the `index\.php` change it to your folder/filename separated by `'|'` in case u have folder named `a, b, c, d` so your `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|a|b|c|d etc etc)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. I still need to type the index.php before the controller name for it find it. Otherwise it sets out an error saying object not found.

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enable on your server configuration ? if its off, this ht access will fail. And i never got problem using this locally with wamp, xampp, or easyPHP with or without virtualhost setup.

Comment: Yes it is enabled by default on EasyPHP Virtual Development Server, and I double checked and indeed it is enabled.

Comment: Well thats strange, i using easyPHP too here. Quite interesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68312/discussion-between-nucleo-1985-and-tyler-lazenby).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is code of .htaccess for remove index.php from urls in codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L] 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|private|public|templates|skin|css|scripts|images|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico) 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and also you need to set blank for index_page in config.php
$config['index_page'] = '';

Comment: add some explanation

Comment: I agree with HaveNoDisplayName, but I am upvoting this anyway because as a reference this is very useful.

Comment: - First you need to blank index.php $config['index_page'] = ''; from config.php
- Then you need to put this htaccess at root folder

Answer (score 0):

change the htaccess file to be in the master folder and then rewrite to equal:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|js|css|uploads|favicon.png)
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Answer Courtesy of Nucleo 1985**

Answer (score 0):

If using xampp I have found that the two example htacess is the best. I see you have not put base url in. Even though codeigniter auto gets base url it all ways best to put your base url in as well in the config.php

**Note:** The deny from all is only used for your application folder and systems folder htaccess files. You most likely do not need to touch the application folders htaccss. If you need to get css and images from your views folder just say allow from all in your application folder htaccess.

For removing of the index.php in url first add  main directory htaccess try. And the remove the index.php from config.php but make sure you add base url.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

or this

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

code for htaccess file is given below...for remove index.php from url...

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
    RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]


</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```